# LangChain: Chunking issue with text_splitter.split_documents & RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=0)

Tags: langchain

I have a set of text files where each file where the file sizes vary from 1K to 2.5k.
Is this possible?

text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=2500, chunk_overlap=0)
texts = text_splitter.split_documents(data)

Comment: Found my issue. Closed Did not read the documentation properly

Comment: how did you fix it?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I changed the chunk size.